# Output data from a MySQL table one time with php

Tags: mysql, database, tags

I have a mysql table with a column that looks something like this:

```
| TAGS |
 ------
|Green |
|Blue  |
|Orange|
|Blue  |
|Green |
| ...  |
 ------
```

Now what I want to do is output all the different tags that exist in a list, BUT every tag can only be outputted once (so e.g. 'Green stands two times in the database but can only stands one time in the list')

Hope you understand my question! 
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and are you selecting any other data? If all you want is the tag, you could use a group by clause to get the unique tags, but that would be if they were in a column. A clearer picture of the table would be nice.

Comment: @czobrisky As you can see, I tried to make a clearer picture But I don't see how a group by clauses is gonna fix the problem.

Comment: `Group by tags` would then only return one of each of the colors in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "row" but do you mean a column labeled "tags" in your table?

There are two different ways:

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

**Method 2:**

```
SELECT tags FROM table_name WHERE condition GROUP BY tags;
```

They both will return a you an array where each item in the row is the tag without repeats (distinct). The main difference is that DISTINCT makes it easier to optimize (and possibly quicker).

Now, if you didn't make a typo and said that you have a row with a column that has multiple tags like:

```
|ROW_ID|TAGS                  |
|   1  |'Blue', 'Red'         |
|   2  |'Red', 'Yellow'       |
|   3  |'Blue', 'Black', 'Red'|
```

Then you'll have to do some parsing and array operations (but that's a completely different answer).

Comment: Sorry, I indeed meant column instead of row, but what do you mean with condition in method 1?

Comment: The condition is just a placeholder where you can add a filter if you want. For example, if you had another column that was a date field, you could not only get all the tags but you could also filter the results for tags between two dates.

If you didn't want to filter you could simply do WHERE 1; or WHERE true;  This will get everything you want.